# adding a sound when pressing an image button

Tags: ios, xcode, image, audio, button

I have this button in the scrollView and i need to play a sound when pressing it.

```
UIButton *profileButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [profileButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [profileButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    profileButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 620, 320, 250);

[self.scrollView addSubview:profileButton];
```

how could i do this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding touch on button press

```
[profileButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonPress) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

// need this include file and the AudioToolbox framework

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

Playing some sound

```
-(void) onButtonPress {
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"mp3"];
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
}
```